# Type . insted of ,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox

I have a textbox in which I want the `.` be typed instead of the `,`.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma) tbPrecio.Text = tbPrecio.Text.Split(',')[0]+".";
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your handler method to:

```
private void tbPrecio_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma)
    {
        tbPrecio.AppendText(".");
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

I think the key addition here is `SuppressKeyPress`.

Comment: but that wont replace , with . i guess it will append.

Comment: Oh yeah, it won't replace any *existing* commas with periods.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a situation where you could use a masked input instead?

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Automatically replacing characters freaks some people out.

Comment: I agree, replacing characters is probably a bad idea, it corrupts the trust between you and your visitor; preventing characters from being typed is understandable, yet still frustrating; but replacing characters will only anger visitors because you're manipulating how their browser functions. There is a sanctity in consistency, messing with input and expected output, takes control away from the user in the most basic fashion and will only give them reason to not visit your site again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private void tbPrecio_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemcomma)
            tbPrecio.Text = tbPrecio.Text.Replace(',','.');
        tbPrecio.Select(tbPrecio.Text.Length, 0);
}
```

But use @Jason's Logic as that's optimal